# Adding value to a cell (within a specified range) populates an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, intersect

My table has a column for *Date & Time* where a current timestamp is added, and another column recording the observed *Number of Events* for that time. I have to fill *Number of Events* quickly, so need the *Date & Time* column (of the same row) to fill automatically with a timestamp upon doing so.

| Date & Time | Number of Events |
| --- | --- |
| 28/9/2022 1:25 pm | 1 |
| 28/9/2022 2:32 pm | 4 |

The code I have currently works to some extent, but has two issues:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        If Intersect(Target, Range("NumberOfEvents")) Is Nothing Or Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row) - 1).Value = Date + Time
End Sub
```

- First, this adds a timestamp to *Date & Time* even when values from *Number of Events* are deleted. Moreover, doing so adds a timestamp to the row above where a value was deleted, corrupting the time data for the
  preceding entry. I need to avoid this. Only adding a value to *Number of Events* should result in a timestamp, not clearing, editing, or double-clicking and pressing enter.
- Second, I sometimes need to revise the number of recorded events
  after filling it, but need *Date and Time* to reflect only the
  timestamp of the initial recording. As it is now, any edit made to
  *Number of Events* creates a new timestamp. I need a code that does not add a new timestamp if a value can already be detected in the respective row of the *Date and Time* column.

I've seen certain examples using the *offset* function, but I'd prefer to avoid this because my table is subject to change. I might need to sandwich in more columns in the future, which would demand rephrasing any offset code.

Thanks in advance to anyone able to help :)

Comment: Is the *NOE* column part of the dynamic range? Is the *DT* column? Where are they located? What should happen if you clear or change one of their cells (in more detail (if...then...))? Where will you be possibly adding columns? Note that when you double-click a cell to change its value and press enter (without changing it), the event will trigger anyway. Also, when you write the timestamp or *NOE*, the event will trigger. Please share more detail by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73889699/edit) at any time.

Comment: Edited the code so that "DynamicRange" is now "NumberofEvents".

Apologies if things weren't clear, but my original post does address your questions.

DT should only be edited when a value is added to NOE. So not when clearing or double-clicking and pressing enter. Changing NOE should add a timestamp to DT only if a timestamp is not already present, so the first instance should be retained.

By 'columns may be sandwiched in' I meant columns may be added between these two columns. DT will always represent the leftmost column though, in column A..

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Conditional Timestamp

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const DRG_COLUMN As String = "A"
    CONST SRG_NAME as string = "NumberOfEvents"
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(Target, Me.Range(SRG_NAME))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no change in range
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Intersect(srg.EntireRow, Me.Columns(DRG_COLUMN))
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sString As String
    Dim drgClear As Range
    Dim drgWrite As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dString As String
    Dim CellIndex As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        sString = CStr(sCell.Value)
        CellIndex = CellIndex + 1
        Set dCell = drg.Cells(CellIndex)
        If Len(sString) = 0 Then ' source cell is blank (Number Of Events)
            Set drgClear = SetBuiltRange(drgClear, dCell)
        Else
            dString = CStr(dCell.Value)
            If Len(dString) = 0 Then ' destination cell is blank (Timestamp)
                Set drgWrite = SetBuiltRange(drgWrite, dCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    If drgClear Is Nothing And drgWrite Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells
            
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not retrigger while modifying
        If Not drgClear Is Nothing Then drgClear.ClearContents
        If Not drgWrite Is Nothing Then drgWrite.Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Function SetBuiltRange( _
    ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set SetBuiltRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set SetBuiltRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```